# How to run sudo -u username command in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to run a specific command as `sudo -u username <command name>` using Ansible.

I tried below task, but facing permissions issue.

```
---
-
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: "Create solr cores"
      shell: /opt/apps/solr/bin/solr create -c test10
      become_flags: '-u solr'
      register: core_one
#      changed_when: '"\"status\":0" in core_one.stdout'
```

Could anyone suggest on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to run a task is the following.

Having proper permissions is a prerequisite. Refer to `man sudoers` to learn more

```
- name: "Create solr cores" 
  shell: /opt/apps/solr/bin/solr create -c test10
  become: yes
  become_user: solr
  register: core_one
```

<sup>You already have `become: yes` on the play level, so just for clarity.</sup>

Comment: Thanks @techraf. I have already tried , but this gives permission denied and gives error in MODULE_FAILURE. Unable to create Ansible related files on node . Here ansible_user and sudo_user are different.

Comment: I have written in the answer that you need to set proper permissions.

Comment: Ansible user should be in sudo_user list to perform this operation.

Comment: @NaggappanRamukannan What is a "*sudo_user list*"?

Comment: Thanks @techraf. It worked. After proper permissions , issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
remote_user: ansible
  tasks:   
  - name: "Create solr cores" 
     shell: /opt/apps/solr/bin/solr create -c test10
     become: yes
     become_user: solr
     register: core_one
```

In above example ansible connects to remote machine using user 'ansible'. Now this ansible user should have permission to switch to another user. i.e it should have root privileges

What happens with above code:

```
* ssh connection is made via ansible user (ansible-play does it)
* It uses command "sudo su solr" internally
* Then execute the command which is mentioned in shell
```

Comment: when I used this , ansible asked for password for solr user.

Comment: machine should not ask for password when you try any command with sudo  (i.e become : yes in ansible). you should set this in the client (node) end. Also make sure "solr" user has sudo access. Try the link to "https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-running-sudo-command-without-a-password/" to run sudo without password